# replaceText wildcard in Google Sheet script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've been trying to work on replacing some text within a Google script but it's not producing what I'd like.  At present I am using Cameron Roberts' script from here - [How do I replace text in a spreadsheet with Google Apps Script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26480857/how-do-i-replace-text-in-a-spreadsheet-with-google-apps-script) to make my replacements however I've not got it quite right.

Using that code I am trying to replace the word 'values' with '1. values' however if I run the code multiple times it produces '1. 1. values' etc as it just finds the 'values' string.  What I'd like is a wildcard which just searches for '*values*' and then puts '1. values' in but I can't seem to grasp the regular expression syntax well enough to fix it.

```
function testReplaceInSheet(){
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
    replaceInSheet(sheet,'values','1. values');
}

function replaceInSheet(sheet, to_replace, replace_with) {
  //get the current data range values as an array
  var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  //loop over the rows in the array
  for(var row in values){

    //use Array.map to execute a replace call on each of the cells in the row.
    var replaced_values = values[row].map(function(original_value){
      return original_value.toString().replace(to_replace,replace_with);
    });

    //replace the original row values with the replaced values
    values[row] = replaced_values;
  }

  //write the updated values to the sheet
  sheet.getDataRange().setValues(values);
}
```

Comment: well, `1. values` contains `values` so it takes that leaving `1. <replace with>` which will be `1. 1. values`. What do you want it to happen? Do nothing?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I'd like to replace 'values' with '1. values' but obviously each time this runs, as you say, I get an additional '1. ' prefixed.I guess what I'd like is the whole string which contains 'values' to be replaced to just show '1. values'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a small change in formatting is acceptable to you then you can capitalize one of the 'values', ex:

```
replaceInSheet(sheet,'values','1. Values');
```

Comment: Of course!  Thanks for this, it should work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

This adds a prefix if the prefix doesn't already exist.
Simulates a negative look behind that's why the reversing is going on

```
function addPrefix(s, find, prefix) {
  function reverse(x) {return x.split("").reverse().join("");}

  var sr = reverse(s);
  var findr = reverse(find);
  var prefixr = reverse(prefix);
  var findRegexpr = new RegExp(findr + "(?!" + prefixr + ")");

  return reverse(sr.replace(findRegexpr, findr + prefixr))
}
```