# Automatically Find&Replace

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, surveymonkey

I work with surveymonkey and when someone doesn't answer my question, my cell is filled with "*Not Answered*".
**The goal is to merge multiple rows into one.**
Possible solutions are:

1. I need a script to **automatically find and replace**. Which will **replace** (more precisely **delete** "*Not Answered*") with an empty cell. So my TEXTJOIN will work. I've tried some code but it doesn't work for the whole sheet.
   The problem with the TEXTJOIN function (delimiter, ignore_empty, text1, [text2, ...]) is that the second parameter igrone_empty is boolean and only works with TRUE or FALSE and cannot write "*Not Answered*" there. So with this I have to find another solution to **ignore** or **delete** the word "*Not Answered*".
2. Alternative to TEXTJOIN where the word "Not Answered" is ignored.
3. Or if it is possible to delete this option in SurveyMonkey?

I have tried this solution but doesn't work for entire sheet/table.

```
 var result = ui.alert(
     "Will update " + to_replace + " to " + replace_with + " ",
     'Are you sure you want to continue?',
      ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);

  // Process the user's response.
  if (result == ui.Button.YES) {

    // User clicked "Yes".
    spread.toast("Will update " + to_replace + " to " + replace_with + " ", "ALERT");

    var data  = range.getValues();

    var oldValue="";
    var newValue="";
    var cellsChanged = 0;

    for (var row=0; row<data.length; row++) {
      for (var item=0; item<data[row].length; item++) {
        oldValue = data[row][item];
        newValue = data[row][item].replace(to_replace, replace_with);
        if (oldValue!=newValue)
        {
          cellsChanged++;
          data[row][item] = newValue;
        }
      }
    }
    range.setValues(data);
    spread.toast(cellsChanged + " cells changed", "STATUS");
  }
  else {
    // User clicked "No" or X in the title bar.
    spread.toast("No action taken", "ABANDONED");
  }
}
```

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Comment: Welcome. Please edit your question to include the code that you have tried. It's important to show your own efforts - partly so that you get feedback and partly so that you show you've made an effort, and don't just want the code written for you..

Comment: "Or if it is possible to delete this option in SurveyMonkey?" If its a "required question, then the user should have no option but to answer. If it's not a required question, then surely you want to know that you user did NOT answer.the question.

Comment: Have you read [Auto-Find and Replace in Google Sheets with Scripts](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/104157/196152), or [How do I replace text in a spreadsheet with Google Apps Script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26480857/1330560)? Perhaps you might care to google "google sheets script find and replace"

Comment: "So my TextJoin will work" I am sure you know what you mean by this reference, but it is not at all clear to anyone reading the question. May I respectfully suggest that you edit your question in order to explain **exactly** what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function replaceNotAnswerWithBlank(e) {
  var ss=e.source;
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var tf=sh.createTextFinder('Not Answered').findAll();
  for(var i=0;i<tf.length;i++) {
    sh.getRange(tf[i].getRow(),tf[i].getColumn()).setValue('');
  }
}
```

How about this:

```
function onOpen(e) {
  replaceNotAnswerWithBlank(e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed a trigger so this is how I solved the problem. If there is a simpler functional solution write it down. Thank you Cooper.

```
function onOpen() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var tf=sh.createTextFinder('Not Answered').findAll();
  replaceNotAnswerWithBlank(ss, sh, rg, tf);
}

function replaceNotAnswerWithBlank(ss, sh, rg, tf) {
  for(var i=0;i<tf.length;i++) {
    sh.getRange(tf[i].getRow(),tf[i].getColumn()).setValue('');
  }
}
```